# Getting data from result set and transposing to file Ruby

Tags: ruby, file

I have result set with some information about a client like

`[{name: John, age:20, state:y, city:w, country:x,...},{name:.....}]`

Now I want to loop through this list getting only name, state, and city. And create a file with this information in the following format

```
name | age | city
```

How can I do this? I thought about adding to a 3d list and then transposing to csv. But I don't like this idea.

Comment: When giving an example always make it complete, as @dawg has done in his answer, so that readers can use it in their answers. Also, always assign data inputs to variables (dawg used the variable `a`) so that readers can simply refer to those variables in their comments and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSV is not that hard to do (using the test data from @dawg):

```
require 'csv'
a = [{name: "John", age:20, state:"ID", city:"Boise", country:"USA"},
  {name: "Bob", age:20, state:"CA", city:"LA", country:"USA"}
]

File.open("test.csv","w") do |f|
  a.each{|hsh| f <<  hsh.values_at(:name, :age, :city).to_csv}
end
```

Comment: `to_csv(col_sep: '|')`

Comment: ...or `CSV.open("test.csv", "w", col_sep: " | ") do |csv| a.each {  |hsh| csv << hsh.values_at(:name, :age, :city)  }; end`. Incidentally, the equals sign is missing in defining `a`.

Comment: If I have a variable "foo" that I want to add to the line. How can I do? Because hsh.values_at(:name, :age, :city).to_csv is getting only from the set, but what if I also want to add another variable in another column

Comment: `a.each{|hsh| f <<  (hsh.values_at(:name, :age, :city) << foo).to_csv}`

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
a=[{name: "John", age:20, state:"ID", city:"Boise", country:"USA"},
   {name: "Bob", age:20, state:"CA", city:"LA", country:"USA"}
]

headers=[:name, :age, :city]
```

You can do:

```
> a.map{|hsh| hsh.slice(*headers) }
=> 
[{:name=>"John", :age=>20, :city=>"Boise"},
 {:name=>"Bob", :age=>20, :city=>"LA"}]
```

And if you want that format:

```
puts headers.join(" | ")
a.map{|hsh| hsh.slice(*headers) }.
    each{|hsh| puts hsh.values.join(" | ")}
```

Prints:

```
name | age | city
John | 20 | Boise
Bob | 20 | LA
```